How to reference a QML Component type in a external JS file
A code like this works just fine:
// file nodeObjects/BaseObject.qml:
Node {
    id: root
    required property string name
    ...
    function getObjectPath(object) {
        let path = ''
        if(object.parent instanceof BaseObject)
            path += getObjectPath(object.parent)
        path += `/${object.name}`
        return path
    }

}

now suppose moving above getObjectPath function to a JS file:
// file /utils.js
function getObjectPath(object) {
    let path = ''
    if(object.parent instanceof BaseObject)
        path += getObjectPath(object.parent)
    path += `/${object.name}`
    return path
}

and use it from components in the usual way:
import '../utils.js' as Utils

...
Utils.getObjectPath(root)

I get the error:

utils.js: ReferenceError: BaseObject is not defined

Tried to import the QML directory as a module (the same practice adopted inside QML Components), but that doesn't seem to work in JS files:
// file /utils.js (top)
.import 'nodeObjects' as NodeObjects

// later use NodeObjects.BaseObject

results in error:

Imported file must be a script

How can such code moved to external JS?

You should define a module; then you can use it to access your component. [ref]
